# Laptop doesn't utilize the full of it's ram after installing xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, performance, ram

I just replaced Windows on my laptop with Xubuntu and, after that, when I start working, there are some performance issues. It seems that the RAM is not fully utilized. It has 8GB installed but only uses about 3.7GB:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7856        1712         763         465        5381        5388
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

Can anyone help me with this? How should I fix this?

Comment: Please show the whole command (command line plus output) by editing your original question. "Mem: 7856" makes me think that Xubuntu is aware of all the memory and uses what it needs. If you start new programs, or new tabs at websites in the web browser, you will see how more memory will be used. (I am not sure where you get "3,7".)

Answer (score 0):

Start more programs :-) ... no, just kidding.

But seriously, you should be glad, that the OS uses just that little RAM, because that means, there is more RAM left for your programs and until then, the OS uses the "unused" RAM as buffer/cache. From my point of view, everything works as expected.

I would suggest to check disk, CPU and network as cause for performance issues and search the log files for warnings and errors.